# forms with different namespace

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have this form:

```
namespace Robo2013
{
    public partial class frm_principal : Form
    {
        public frm_principal()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

This form have one treeview and one panel, the treeview show form on the panel with this code

```
   private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
   {
        //Grande If, else para selecionar os forms a partir do clique de um node.
        if (treeView1.SelectedNode.Text == "Grupo")
        {
            panelmain.Controls.Clear();
            frm_grupo grupo = new frm_grupo();
            grupo.TopLevel = false;
            grupo.AutoScroll = true;
            panelmain.Controls.Add(grupo);
            grupo.Show();
        }
   }
```

That work fine, but I want to call other form , from the panel with a button:

```
namespace Robo2013.Robo_Forms 
{
    public partial class Frm_robo_email : Form
    {
        public Frm_robo_email()
        {  
            InitializeComponent(); 
        }

        private void btn_configuracoes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

How to call the form to a panel if have diferent namespaces

Comment: Exactly what problem do you have to call the other form? Please show us what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

From the MSDN documentation:

> The namespace keyword is used to declare a scope that contains a set
>   of related objects. You can use a namespace to organize code elements
>   and to create globally unique types.

You need to instantiate an instance of the other form with either the fully qualified namespace or relative namespace or by adding a `using` directive to your C# class file.
**Fully qualified namespace:**

```
Robo2013.Robo_Forms.Frm_robo_email emailFrm = new Robo2013.Robo_Forms.Frm_robo_email();
emailFrm.Show();
```

**Relative namespace:**

```
Robo_Forms.Frm_robo_email emailFrm = new Robo_Forms.Frm_robo_email();
emailFrm.Show();
```

**`using` directive:**

```
using Robo2013.Robo_Forms;

...

Frm_robo_email emailFrm = new Frm_robo_email();
emailFrm.Show();
```

Note, that to use a relative namespace, you need to be referencing a child namespace from a parent namespace. The parent namespace in this case is Robo2013.

Here is more information on using namespaces in C#: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfb3cx8s.aspx